# How to get data from a child route component

Tags: typescript, angular5, angular-router

What is the proper way to handle this please?

I have a parent route which has a create team form and child routes that load various filtered tables (these are multi select tables)

The parent component:

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./users.component.scss']
})
export class UsersComponent implements OnInit {

  organization: Organization;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute,
    private teamService: TeamService,
    private oauthService: OAuthService) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.parent.data.subscribe(data => {
      this.organization = data['organization'];
    });
  }

  onCreateTeam(data) {
    this.teamService.createTeam({
      name: data.name,
      organizationId: this.organization.id,
      userIds: [...]
    });
  }

}
```

One of the child route components

```
@Component({
  templateUrl: './all-users.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./all-users.component.scss']
})
export class AllUsersComponent implements OnInit {

  @ViewChild(DtNavbarComponent) navbar: DtNavbarComponent;

  teams: Team[];
  selectedUsers: SystemUser[];

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

Each child route component is similar and will have a `selectedUsers` property which will hold the users selected from the multi select table

Now, in the parent component the user can enter the team name and select one or more users, then when the user clicks create I want to be able to submit the DTO to the server in the parent component:

```
onCreateTeam(data) {
    this.teamService.createTeam({
      name: data.name,
      organizationId: this.organization.id,
      userIds: [...] // this needs to be the property `selectedUsers` from the child route component
    });
}
```

So my question is how would I go about accessing the `selectedUsers` property from the child route component when the user click on create?